# How to get Width of a Grid on Property Changed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, width

I would like to get a `Grid`'s actual `Width` (or `Height`) and display it in a textbox, but the width/height should be "live", when I resize the window I would like to see the new sizes.

How do I do this?

**Update:**

With regard to [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252010/how-to-get-width-of-a-grid-on-property-changed-in-wpf/2252026#2252026):

This works fine but now i would like to go a step further.

I need the actual width in a variable for testing purposes like to set some if statements or to scale other objects that are in a grid.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">...</Grid>

<TextBox Text="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=myGrid}" />
```

(The `TextBox` could, of course, be inside the `Grid`.)

The trick is that `Width` only specifies the initial width of a control. `ActualWidth` is the "live" property you should bind to.

Comment: and actually, the `Actual*` properties reside quite high up in the hierarchy and are therefore available on many other controls besides the grid.

Comment: nice :D thx... any idea how to implent this "only" in codebehind? for example if i create a grid mygrid = new grid() and the tb TextBox mytb = new TextBox() how to assign it there? .. mytb.Text=mygrid.actualwidth; ? or something with property changed or like this?

Comment: Same thing in code:
mytb.SetBinding(TextProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source=mygrid });

Comment: @John I think that'd be { ElementName = "myGrid" }, wouldn't it? Or would Source work too?

Comment: @Matt - No, that would only work if you defined an element named "myGrid" in XAML in the same scope where you're adding the TextBox. Variable names don't carry over from code into XAML. ElementName is actually just a shortcut for setting the Source that's used to get around the fact that you can't bind an element to a property of a binding in XAML (this was a problem in Silverlight pre-3.0). They have the same effect but use different types of references.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second set of questions:

You can add a `DependencyProperty` to the `Window` and bind it to the `ActualHeight` of the `Grid` in the same way the `Text` property of the `TextBox` was bound.

It is also possible to bind other properties of other controls to the `ActualHeight` of the `Grid`. If you need a calculation inbetween use a `ValueConverter` to change the value to something you need.